# Android - Animate a View's entrance

Tags: android, animation

How can I animate the way a certain View first appears (transitions) onto the screen? I know how to build the animation, I'm just wondering how to make it so that the animation is run as the view is first drawn onto the screen.

Appreciate any and all help!

Edit: The View in question would be a TextView or an ImageView.

Comment: the answer might change depending on the View type, are you referring to a small TextView? or a full screen FragmentTransaction transition? try to be more percise

Answer (score 3):

You can set layout attribute

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

in parent layout, so all actions like changing child view Visibility from VISIBLE to GONE will be animated.
Or if you need certain type of animation - just create animation and use it in the correct time (for example when screen is created, or some action that cause view appearing happened).

Comment: This will animate it, but it won't animate it based on his custom animation. It will use the SDK's default animation. But if that's what he wants, then this is a good solution.

Comment: I actually do have a custom animation, my understanding is that I would need to inject my animation sometime after onCreateView() (working with a fragment) would any of the subsequent methods work to make it seem like the view slid onto the screen for the first time? or is there a preferred/recommended life-cycle method for this sort of thing?

Comment: I don't know for sure, try setting it in onCreateView on in onStart

Answer (score 0):

You could create the view programmatically then animate it. I'll use a TextView as an example.

```
TextView tv = new TextView(context);
tv.startAnimation(yourAnimation);
```

These 2 lines need to be called after you call setContentView or (if in a fragment) you `return view` in `onCreateView()`

If you need to set properties to that view you'll need to set them programmatically as well. i.e

```
tv.setTypeFace(null, TypeFace.BOLD);
```

to set your TextView's typeface to bold.

There are other ways of doing this such as making a view set visibility to gone or invisible and then animate it to being visible. (Giving the effect of it loading for the first time)

Comment: Why not animate inflated view the same way?

Comment: In the case of a fragment what method exactly would I override where I could set the animations after the view has been returned in onCreateView